# cannot recall original 'x' variable of function object?

Tags: javascript, canvas

If an object's, e.g. this:

```
function Circle (a,y,r)
```

variable **a** has been called later in form:

```
Circle(var1+var2++, y,r);
```

or.

```
Circle(var1+var2,y,r);
xInc = 1;
var2 += xInc;
```

Is there a way to recall original 'a' variable for the conditional? Have already tried direct calling of object parameter like:

```
if (Circle.x > 40) { xInc = -xInc };
```

So long as it's constructive, feel free to pull my current understanding(s) to pieces ;]

Comment: It might be me nitpicking, but I'd prefer `var1+(var2++)` or `var1 + var2++` for debugging purposes.

Comment: The whole context of your issue is quite unclear. What is this "object" about to do. It's just initial line of its declaration. Where is this conditional located? Inside that Object's code (obviously not)? How come you want access `a` in property `x`. This is too little code ...

Comment: why not have a statement that says `var x = var1 + var2++` then call `Circle(x, y, r);` and then have the `if (x > 40){xInc =- xInc};`?

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking here.. I almost voted to close it. Why don't you edit the question with the definition inside Circle? You're later doing Circle.x, while we don't know how it's been defined. You're not even using it as an object here as you are not setting it to any object.

Answer (score 1):

When you call a function, you pass an expression to it.

The result of evaluating the expression will be stored in a variable that is local to that function.

Unless either:

- the function explicitly copies it somewhere else
- you already have a copy of it somewhere else

…it will not be available outside the function.